# Fragment: Callback inside onTextChanged null after orientation change despite using onAttach()

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, callback, orientation-changes

My Fragment always throws

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void FragmentClass$InputCallbacks.OnTextChanged(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

because of the line:

```
UserInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                mListener.OnTextChanged(s);
            }
        });
```

My other uses of mListener aren't throwing something.
I guess it's because of the use of new Textwatcher(){....} but I'm not experienced enough to solve that by myself :-/

The whole class throwing the error:

```
public class ToolbarInputOneAddress extends Fragment {
    private InputCallbacks mListener;

    public ToolbarInputOneAddress() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toolbar_input_one_address, container, false);
        Address address = mListener.getAddress();
        EditText UserInput = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.InputField);

        if (address != null) {
            StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder();
            UserInput.setText(SuggestAddresses.createFormattedAddressFromAddress(address, Sb));
        }
        UserInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                mListener.OnTextChanged(s);
            }
        });

        ImageButton ReturnButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_navigation_drawer_back);
        ReturnButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mListener.onReturnButtonClicked();
            }
        });

        return v;
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (InputCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement InputCallbacks");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface InputCallbacks {
        void OnTextChanged(CharSequence s);

        void onReturnButtonClicked();

        Address getAddress();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried to set `android:configChanges="orientation"` in your `activity` on `Manifest`

Comment: No, because I don't handle that myself.

Comment: Your activity has implemented `InputCallbacks`?

Comment: It's just a name I made up :-)
Renamed it to `Callbacks`, same problem

Comment: The problem is definitely, that `mListener` inside `onTextChanged` is `null` after an orientation change.

The Strange part is, that the `OnClickListener` used for the `ReturnButton` still has a valid `mListener` after an orientation change.....

Is there something special about TextWatcher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it.
I declare my callbacks in fragments in groups like this like this

```
public interface $Callbacks {
        void $Callback1(String s);
        void $Callback2();
        Address $Callback2();
    }
```

Turns out I had multiple Callback Groups defined with the same name. I thought this is okay, because I state that explicitly with `implements` in my activity.

Since I changed the callback groups names to different ones I don't get the NPE anymore:

TL,DR:

I changed

`implements $fragment1.callbacks $fragment2.callbacks $fragment3.callbacks`

to

`implements $fragment1.f1callbacks $fragment2.f2callbacks $fragment3.f3callbacks`

In my activity implementing said fragment callbacks